# C++ program builds successfully, but get error when running

Tags: c++

```
Matrix &Matrix::operator*(Matrix &rhs) {
    if (this->columns != rhs.rows) {
        this->~Matrix();
        return *this;
    }
    else {
        Matrix product(this->rows, rhs.columns);


        /*for (unsigned int col = 0; col < product.columns; col++) {
            for (unsigned int row = 0; row < product.rows; row++) {
                unsigned int val = 0;
                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->columns; i++) {
                    val += this->get(row, i)*rhs.get(i, col);
                }
                product.set(row, col, val);
            }
        }*/

        return product;
    }
```

The code builds, but crashes when running. When debugging I get that the message that the error lies in the copy constructor (`this->matrix = new double[rows*columns];`)

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix&m):rows(m.rows),columns(m.columns),matrix(nullptr) {
    if (!m.isValid()) {
        return;
    }
    this->matrix = new double[rows*columns];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows*columns; i++) {
        matrix[i] = m.matrix[i];
    }
}
```

I don't understand why? The copy constructor was working as it should just before I implemented the `*` operator. I commented out piece by piece to find the real error, and it seems like the program crashes due to the return product; statement. And this is when I have commented out the for-loops, so those are not the problem.

My testing from main is simply:

```
#include "Source.h"
#include "Matrix.h"
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    Matrix A(3,3);
    Matrix B(3);
    cout << B << endl;
    cout << A << endl;
    Matrix C=A*B;
    cout << C << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I hope anyone can help me, because I am really stuck.
Here are the links to the whole program:

- Header: https://codeshare.io/Wn0do
- Source: https://codeshare.io/AGkYV

Comment: That the program compiles just means that it is syntactically valid. That means nothing towards producing the result you want or whether or not it has defined behaviour at runtime.  Just a note.

Comment: It doesn't help that you're returning a *reference* to a *local temporary variable* in your operator. That's UB.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. Also `this->~Matrix();` looks super wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operator *` method in your code returns a reference to a local variable. The local variable `product` goes out of scope and is destroyed when you `return` hence you end up returning a dangling reference, using which you probably end up with undefined behaviour.

The return type of `operator *` should probably be just `Matrix` instead of `Matrix &`:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator*(Matrix &rhs) { /* ... your code here ... */ }
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, that really helped. That was really sloppy of me:/